# Unplace all widgets from canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm using `place()`, and instead of `place_forget()`ing manually each widget, is there any way to unplace all widgets placed on the `canvas_resources`?

```
    from Tkinter import *

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")

    canvas_state=1

    def toggle(event):
        global canvas_state
        if canvas_state==0:
            btn1_res.place_forget()
            btn2_res.place_forget()
            canvas_state=1
            return

        if canvas_state==1:
            btn1_res.place(x=30, y=10)
            btn2_res.place(x=30, y=50)
            canvas_state=0
            return

    canvas_resources = Canvas(root, height=200, width=100, bg='#182219')
    canvas_resources.place(x=-2, y=-2)
    btn1_res = Button(canvas_resources, text='TEXT1')
    btn2_res = Button(canvas_resources, text='TEXT2')
    btn3_res = Button(root, text='TEXT3')
    btn3_res.place(x=150, y=150)

    root.bind('<Return>', toggle)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, following the orientations from @BryanOakley, adding `canvas.place_slaves()` in a loop did what I asked for.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

canvas_state=1

def toggle(event):
    global canvas_state
    if canvas_state==0:
        for item in canvas_resources.place_slaves():
            item.place_forget()
        canvas_state=1
        return

    if canvas_state==1:
        btn1_res.place(x=30, y=10)
        btn2_res.place(x=30, y=50)
        canvas_state=0        
        return

canvas_resources = Canvas(root, height=200, width=100, bg='#182219')
canvas_resources.place(x=-2, y=-2)
btn1_res = Button(canvas_resources, text='TEXT1')
btn2_res = Button(canvas_resources, text='TEXT2')
btn3_res = Button(root, text='TEXT3')
btn3_res.place(x=150, y=150)


root.bind('<Return>', toggle)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: code-only answers aren't very useful to others. You should explain the differences so that other people don't have to compare your code line-by-line to the original.

Comment: Taking the info that was provided to you in an answer and then answer your own question with that info is in pore taste. Bryan's answer was the correct answer to get you to a solution. You should delete this post and accept Bryan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. If you want to "unplace" widgets added with `place`, the only option is to call `place_forget` for every widget.

You can use `place_slaves` to get a list of all widgets managed by `place` within another widget. For example, you could do it like this:

```
for widget in canvas_resources.place_slaves():
    widget.place_forget()
```

Comment: Oh, bad news.. There's almost 50 widgets I'll need to delete one by one then. :(

Comment: @MaiconErick: you can do it in a loop. `canvas.place_slaves()` will return a list.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but exclude 1 specific label? but remove all other labels?

Comment: @Minbutt: yes, of course. Just add an `if` statement inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing it like this: `def clear(self, cont):
        for label in second_frame.place_slaves():
            label.place_forget()
            if label == 'title':
                label.place()` however it didn't seem to work. 'title' is the name of the label I don't want to forget.